# Differences beetween ModalController and NavController

Tags: ionic2

I need to understand the differences between ModalController and NavController in Ionic 2. When should I choose NavController and when to choose ModalController?

Comment: can i know the reason for downvote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [ModalController doc](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/modal/ModalController/):

> A modal uses the NavController to present itself in the root nav
>   stack. It is added to the stack similar to how NavController.push
>   works.

So we can say, in mechanism, they are the same. Lets talk about UX.

> A Modal is a content pane that goes over the user's current page

A modal actually go over the page. It is like a popup. In small device, it take all the space of screen so you can not realize the diffentce from it and page. But if you test it in tablet like a ipad you will see the modal just take a part of screen and the current page is behind it.(Image description below).
[image]

**What should be used?**
In most case, you can use modal or page base on what you prefer but to ensure the properly UX modal should be used in case editing, making choice or getting information, other case page should be used

Answer (score 1):

The [ModalController](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/modal/ModalController/) is used to create and present modals. Modals are commonly used for galleries, edit forms, and other content that should be push on top of the current page.

```
import { ModalController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Page1 } from './pages';

constructor(private modalCtrl: ModalController) {}

let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(Page1);
modal.present();
modal.onDidDismiss(() => {
  // Action done after dismissing the modal.
});
```

The [NavController](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/) is used for navigation functionality (think about Tabs or just basic page navigation). This controller also contains your navigation history.

```
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Page1 } from './pages';

constructor(private navCtrl: NavController) {

}

this.navCtrl.push(Page1);
```

So there are two different approaches to present the desired page. For more information/options/methods please ready the provided links, containing all available features available on the Modal- and NavController components.